# How to set elevation to Bottom navigation

Tags: android, material-design

So by the `support V25`. We have new component called Bottom navigation.

Follow the Design guidelines, the Bottom Navigation's `elevation` should be `8dp` (https://material.io/guidelines/components/bottom-navigation.html#bottom-navigation-specs)

But I can't set the `elevation` to it.

Any suggestion, example would be appreciated. Thank you!

**UPDATE XML CODE**

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_color_state"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
    android:background="#EDEDED"/>
```

Comment: post your XML code containing bottom navigation.

Comment: check [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226182&sort=-id%20-stars%20-status&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316411/bottomnavigationview-shadow-and-ripple-effect)

Comment: Try this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650778/android-bottom-navigation-bar-with-drop-shadow/41651284#41651284

Comment: @AlexanderBilchuk, it won't cast the shadow on top of other view

Comment: @gopal_patil, updated to 25.1.0, replace app:itemBackground with android:background, still can't cast shadow

Answer (score 39, accepted):

So, for now (25.1.0) we have to set the `android:background` of BNV to `@android:color/white` to have the shadow. It will not display if you set to other color (ie your primary color)

Comment: confirming solution. important (and weird) part is that **must** be `white` color (from `android` res or "custom" - but not so custom if it has to be white...). not working with black and any other...

Comment: In this situation, if `app:elevation` is going to be used, it adds some shadow on bottom of navigation view. If I want to add the shadow on top of navigation, what should I do? @NamNguyễn

Comment: tried today - any color works, but to drop shadow you will still need android:background to be set

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and to have a `@android:color/white` as OP suggested was not acceptable in my case. So since we "can't" get shadow with elevation and custom background we need to hack it.

My approach is adding a shadow view inside the frame layout to "mimic" elevation.

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@drawable/bottom_nav_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@drawable/bottom_nav_color_state"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentFrame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
    android:background="#EDEDED"/>

    <some.kind.of.pager.or.other.content.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/shadow_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="4dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_gradient" />

</FrameLayout>
```

where the background of the shadow view is nothing more than a shape gradient that is positioned over all other just above the bottom nav view, something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="#8f000000" />
</shape>
```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 2):

Elevation has been fixed in the Android material components 1.1.0 (alpha) release according to [this](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/commit/560c9822844608da6ea16c0c4815eb437d819fc1) commit.

**Edit**

for those wondering, this is how you add the new depdendency:

```
dependencies {
    // ...
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha02'
    // ...
}
```

More information about getting started can be found [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md) and info about releases can be found [here](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/releases).

Cheers!

Comment: How would I go about using it?

Comment: Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@appComponentFactory value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory) from [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
 is also present at [androidx.core:core:1.0.0] AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-86 value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory).

Comment: I get this error. I honestly don't like to mess with Gradle because it is a pain in the head.

Comment: The commit is related to `BottomAppBar` which is a totally different component. The OP is asking about `BottomNavigationView`. Please read the question carefully before answering.