# Elevation issue when coloring BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, material-design, android-bottomnav

I want to implement colored `BottomNavigationView` with `elevation` (current design lib version 25.2.0, test device 7.1.2). Some code for start:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:elevation="8dp"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation" />
```

elevation (shadow) is not drawn, because there is no background. and there is [known issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823599/how-to-set-elevation-to-bottom-navigation) that this background **must be white**... ok, so I'm adding this line

```
    android:background="@android:color/white"
```

but I wanted to set some color for background and white icons and text... with below lines

```
    app:itemIconTint="@color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/white"
```

whole bar is solid white, including content, obviusly... so if `background` must be white also then lets change every item background with

```
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/bottom_navigation_item_background"
```

and for drawable/

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/mycolor_dark"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/mycolor"/>
</selector>
```

for drawable-v21/ (ripple)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:color="@android:color/white">
    <item android:drawable="@color/mycolor"/>
</ripple>
```

and now we have colored items and... no elevation again! and it will work when `mycolor` will be white (elevation shown/drawn)... so when I want elevation for `BottomNavigationView` both `background` and `itemBackground` must be white...

interesting part (proof of issue?) - lets check elevation with only this selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@android:color/white"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/mycolor"/>
</selector>
```

bar is drawn without elevation at all, but when I press any menu item then its background change to white and... there is elevation above this item, ONLY this item!

when I remove `<item android:drawable="@color/mycolor"/>` line from drawable-v21/ XML file (or set `mycolor` to white), then elevation is shown. ripple color have no impact, it might be white or any other (working).

the question is: **how to style `BottomNavigationView` with custom color for background keeping elevation working?**

Answer (score 0):

I used `app:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"` in order to use my application colors. They are automatically set to them.
For example, if your primary color is green, icons and text will be displayed in green.
You need to keep white background and elevation...