# Ripple effect in BottomNavigation view

Tags: android, navigation, bottomnavigationview

In my BottomNavigationView, I want to add ripple effect and then change the background color of my selected navigation item. Here is a screenshot of what i've done so far[image]

My Drawable File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorAccent" android:state_checked="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/colorPrimaryDark" android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

My Layout File

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/navigaton_item_bg"
    app:itemIconTint="@android:color/white"
    app:itemTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316411/bottomnavigationview-shadow-and-ripple-effect

Comment: I tried that already. When i add ripple effect then i can not change my selected item's background color @NileshRathod