# ButtomNavigationView doesn't show ripple effect in Items Background

Tags: android

**UPDATE:**

The other question uses a white background and since it uses white background there is no ripple on the BottomNavigationBar (because the ripple itself is white). But in my case the ButtomNavigationBar is blue, and it reflects the ripple. In fact all of the colors except the white(that the other question uses) reflect the incomplete  ripple.

**ORIGINAL:**

I am using ButtomNavigationView, and the problem is that it doesn't show ripple effect in the background of it's Items.

Or it doesn't care about **app:itemBackground** it just uses **android:background** value without any ripple effect.

I've tried using a *ripple*  instead of *selector* in drawable-21 and changing the **app:itemBackground** color values but it is not working.

ButtomNavigationView:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:theme="@style/BottomNavigationStyle"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

ButtomNavigationStyle:

```
<style name="BottomNavigationStyle">
    <item name="itemBackground">@drawable/navigation_bar_item_bg</item>
    <item name="itemIconTint">?attr/bottom_nav_colors</item>
    <item name="itemTextColor">?attr/bottom_nav_colors</item>
    <item name="android:background">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/iransans_mobile</item>
 </style>
```

bottom_nav_menu:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
 <item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_mylibrary"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_library_books_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_mylibrary" />
 <item
    android:id="@+id/navigation_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/title_search" />
    .
    .
    .
 </menu>
```

navigation_bar_item_bg:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_color"  
    android:state_checked="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/black_color"/>
</selector>
```

ScreenShot:

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/library-1696f.appspot.com/o/Screenshot%20from%202019-06-17%2005-39-23.png?alt=media&token=20efbe56-3234-47ab-b6cc-898124b77762

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BottomNavigationView - Shadow and Ripple Effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40316411/bottomnavigationview-shadow-and-ripple-effect)

Answer (score 0):

I've searched and I've found that it is a library bug that is not fixed yet.

But I've found a solution for this.

1) Since the **android:background** and **android:itemBackground** don't work correctly delete both of them from BottomNavigationView.

2) Create a new *FrameLayout* and put your *BottomNavigationView* inside *FrameLayout*.

3) change these properties of the FrameLayout:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

4)Finally Add your desired color for ButtomNavigationView into FrameLayout as **android:background**.

Example:

```
<FrameLayout
 android:id="@+id/buttomnavigation_container"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:background="@color/blue"><!--Background color for BNV-->
 <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_navigation_colors"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_navigation_colors"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

bottom_navigation_colors.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item
        android:state_checked="true"
        android:color="#FFFFFF" />
   <item
       android:state_checked="false"
       android:color="#C7FFFFFF" />
</selector>
```

[image]